# minimizing the value of a simple expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to minimize this very simple expression, and understand that the square root of 20 would offer a minimal value > 0:

$$n + \frac{20}{n}$$

Can anyone explain or prove why $\sqrt{20}$ would minimize this expression. Thanks!

Comment: AM-GM inequality?

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be a natural number? Then the square root of 20 can't be a minimal value. Also, are you allowed to use calculus?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x + { 20 \over x}$ for $x >0$. Note that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, so $f$ has a minimum in $(0,\infty)$.
Then $f'(x) = 1-{20 \over x^2}$, and $f'(x) = 0$ **iff** $x =  \sqrt{20}$, hence this must be the minimizer.

Comment: What is $\infty$? You should write $+\infty$ instead. Also, $\sqrt{20}$ is not the minimum, but the value at which the minimum is obtained. The minimum is $x=2\sqrt{20}$

Comment: Why should I put a $+$ there???? There is no confusion.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: Well, it is. $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} {1 \over x} = \infty$.

Comment: No, it is not. It is $\lim_{x\rightarrow o^+}=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow o^-}=-\infty$.

Comment: The domain is $x>0$. There is no need to be so incredibly pedantic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13320/discussion-between-alex-and-copper-hat)

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n)=n+20/n$ then $f(n)-2\sqrt{20}=(n-\sqrt{20})^2/n.$ So provided $n>0$ the minimal value is $2\sqrt{20}$ and occurs when $n=\sqrt{20}.$

Answer (score 0):

This solution employs an alternative to a calculus approach.

We can assume, for the sake of applying the AM-GM inequality, that $n > 0$ because if $n < 0$, then $n + \frac{20}{n} < 0$, but we are looking for least positive value of $n + \frac{20}{n}$. Then, applying the AM-GM inequality, we have:

$$\frac{n + \frac{20}{n}}{2} \ge \sqrt{n\cdot\frac{20}{n}}\\
n + \frac{20}{n} \ge 2\sqrt{20}$$

with inequality at $n  = \frac{20}{n} \implies n = \sqrt{20}$.